# JavaScript seeting selectedIndex to be blank for select do not work

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make default selection of a dropdown selection to be blank.

If I generate a select dropdown with HTML, it works.
However when I generate the same dropdown with javascript, it does not work.

Please see 
http://jsfiddle.net/m2HSb/

```
<select id="myDropdown">      
    <option>Option 1</option>     
    <option>Option 2</option>     
    <option>Option 3</option>     
</select> 

<div id="yo"></div>

document.getElementById("myDropdown").selectedIndex = -1

var my_select = document.createElement("select")
for ( var i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ ) {
    my_select.options[i] = new Option(i,i)    
}
my_select.selectedIndex = -1
document.getElementById("yo").appendChild(my_select)
```

Note that the first dropdown is blank, and the second is not.

Comment: Do you hate semi-colons for a reason?

Comment: it doesn't make a difference, right?

Comment: It often doesn't make a difference. As a result people disagree on their usage.

Comment: It's sort-of optional, but I must confess that I prefer to explicitly terminate lines. It makes it easier, for me, to manage code when I'm editing, copying and pasting when I'm writing JavaScript functions and such. Maybe I've spent too much time with JS Lint/JS Hint, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you can't set the `selectedIndex` of a `select` element that hasn't been inserted into the DOM yet.

If you move `my_select.selectedIndex = -1` after the `append` then it works fine.

```
var my_select = document.createElement("select");
for ( var i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ ) {
    my_select.options[i] = new Option(i,i);
}
document.getElementById("yo").appendChild(my_select);
my_select.selectedIndex = -1;
```

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m2HSb/1/).